# When I use $scope.watch in angular, I have an issue in passing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I use $scope.watch and set and get to pass one data from one controller to another. This works fine, but when I do this with different html files, data is not transferred in my first click. because browser is refreshed. But when I click go back arrow in chrome and set a value and clicked, I can get the value in my second page. How can I resolve this. Please tell me solution.

```
var data = {
    Quantity: ''
};
return {
    getQuantity: function() {
        return data.Quantity;
    },
    setQuantity: function(quantity) {
        data.Quantity = quantity;
    }
};
.controller('DetailsCtrl', function($scope, $http, Data) {
    $scope.quantity = '';
    $scope.$watch('quantity', function(newValue50, oldValue50) {
        if (newValue50 !== oldValue50)
            Data.setQuantity(newValue50);
    });
})

.controller('FifthCtrl', function($scope, $http, Data) {
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return Data.getQuantity();
    }, function(newValue50, oldValue50) {
        if (newValue50 !== oldValue50)
            $scope.quantity = newValue50;
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the value between different sessions in the browser you could add the quantity value to the [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Here's an angularjs service/factory example

```
app.factory('Data', function () {

    var data = {
        Quantity: ''
    };

    return {
        getQuantity: function () {

            if (localStorage.getItem("data") === null) {
                data.Quantity = 0;
            } else {
                var jsonData = localStorage.getItem('data');
                data.Quantity = JSON.parse(jsonData);
            }

            return data.Quantity;
        },
        setQuantity: function (quantity) {
            data.Quantity = quantity;
            localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    };
});
```

Note 1: You actually don't need the object 'data' in this case as you store the value in the storage but I let it stand as is.

Note 2: The localStorage can't store complext types such as objects and you need to make strings of them before you store them, thats why the JSON.stringify() is used.